# Pandas to_sql() performance related to number of columns

Tags: pandas

I noticed some odd behaviour of a script of mine which uses pandas' to_sql function to insert large numbers of rows into one of my mssql server.
The performance dramatically decreases when the number of columns exceeds 10

For example:

34484 rows x 10 columns => ~10k records per second

34484 rows x 12 columns => ~500 records per second

I use the fast_executemany Flag when establishing the conneciton, anyone got any idea!?

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s?charset=utf8" % params, fast_executemany=True)
sqlalchemy_connection = engine.connect()
....
df.to_sql(name='TEST', con=sqlalchemy_connection , if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: Did you try `method='multi'` in the `to_sql()` method?

Comment: Without a chunksize "multi" won't work it seems, but the performance stays the same (and if I go over a certain chunksize of a few hundred it dies with an obscure error message)

Comment: Sure thing. Are the extra 2 columns indexed by the DB? Do you have a chance to test it without using sqlalchemy?  Could you try using 10 columns including those extra 2 and removing another 2?

Comment: @PauloMarques: The Table has no index at all, created it just for the test, tried to switch columns around, no change, always after 10 columns the performance degrades extremely. Regarding switching out sqlalchemy, I changed it now to pyodbc (also with fast_executemany), performance is even a little bit worse :)

Comment: I will do the same when I have a chance. Meanwhile if you get a satisfactory answer, let us know

Comment: Just as an info, the bug does not happen on postgresql, there the performance os ~14k records per second